# Is it possible to call js method from class in ASP.NET Web Forms?

Tags: javascript, c#, webforms

I have a javascript file to add product to database and I want to call it from class in backend. Is it possible? Btw: I found nothing about this

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with

```
Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(),"CallMyFunction","MyFunction()",true);
```

[MSDN Docs on the method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z9h4dk8y(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: So, if I have js file sample.js, I need to replace `CallMyFunction` with its path?

Comment: No, you should not. You just need to refer `sample.js` on your aspx page.

Comment: @Eugene is correct (never noticed the comment from OP). Add the script file inside <script> tags on the aspx/cshtml file then it can be called with the above method from the code behind at any point.

Answer (score 1):

If you have UpdatePanel on page then you can  use below script

```
  ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, GetType(), "keyToRegister", "MyFunction();", true);
```